# Bold letters within minted (bash/text)

Tags: listings, bold, minted, sharelatex, emphasis

I need to emphasise one entries in this liste of number, but I can't seem to use `\textbf{}` or something similar in within a `minted` workspace.  How do I emphasise certain within minted?

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minted}[autogobble,xleftmargin=0.1\textwidth,xrightmargin=0.1\textwidth,frame=single]{bash}
        [[  1.21105916e-03   9.98751879e-01   3.69788831e-05]]
        [[  9.31845248e-01   8.14934465e-05   6.80731535e-02]]
        [[  2.51991690e-08   1.38797950e-05   9.99986053e-01]]
        [[  2.20720409e-04   3.13331257e-05   9.99747932e-01]]
        [[  2.88604596e-03   9.97110307e-01   3.71164833e-06]]
        [[  9.65342045e-01   1.14912807e-04   3.45430225e-02]]
        [[  9.35987046e-05   2.29562909e-04   9.99676824e-01]]
        [[  3.64742687e-06   1.02245028e-03   9.98973966e-01]]
        [[  9.98075962e-01   1.79647308e-04   1.74431293e-03]]
        [[  7.45317191e-02   9.24890220e-01   5.78058825e-04]]
        [[  4.23816502e-01   1.95193406e-05   5.76164007e-01]]
        [[  5.45647919e-01   1.01446029e-04   \textbf{4.54250574e-01}]]
        ....
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this supported in sharelatex?... @koleygr

Comment: sharelatex just runs latex... It is not a new language (you just use their service to avoid installing for some reason). see here related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260551/minted-mathescape. Also why minted inside listing?

Comment: Listing is used for adding caption and label...  The reason why I ask whether it is supported on sharelatex, is as it doesn't work.. 

I am able to get it into normal text format, but not in bold

Comment: Ok... trying now...

Comment: removing my comment... it doesn't work... but looking to find it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}


    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,autogobble,xleftmargin=0.1\textwidth,xrightmargin=0.1\textwidth,frame=single]{python}
        [[  1.21105916e-03   9.98751879e-01   3.69788831e-05]]
        [[  9.31845248e-01   8.14934465e-05   6.80731535e-02]]
        [[  2.51991690e-08   1.38797950e-05   9.99986053e-01]]
        [[  2.20720409e-04   3.13331257e-05   9.99747932e-01]]
        [[  2.88604596e-03   9.97110307e-01   3.71164833e-06]]
        [[  9.65342045e-01   1.14912807e-04   3.45430225e-02]]
        [[  9.35987046e-05   2.29562909e-04   9.99676824e-01]]
        [[  3.64742687e-06   1.02245028e-03   9.98973966e-01]]
        [[  9.98075962e-01   1.79647308e-04   1.74431293e-03]]
        [[  7.45317191e-02   9.24890220e-01   5.78058825e-04]]
        [[  4.23816502e-01   1.95193406e-05   5.76164007e-01]]
        [[  5.45647919e-01   1.01446029e-04  |$\bm{4.54250574e-01}$|]]
        ....
    \end{minted}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

This is using text:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}


    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,autogobble,xleftmargin=0.1\textwidth,xrightmargin=0.1\textwidth,frame=single]{python}
        [[  1.21105916e-03   9.98751879e-01   3.69788831e-05]]
        [[  9.31845248e-01   8.14934465e-05   6.80731535e-02]]
        [[  2.51991690e-08   1.38797950e-05   9.99986053e-01]]
        [[  2.20720409e-04   3.13331257e-05   9.99747932e-01]]
        [[  2.88604596e-03   9.97110307e-01   3.71164833e-06]]
        [[  9.65342045e-01   1.14912807e-04   3.45430225e-02]]
        [[  9.35987046e-05   2.29562909e-04   9.99676824e-01]]
        [[  3.64742687e-06   1.02245028e-03   9.98973966e-01]]
        [[  9.98075962e-01   1.79647308e-04   1.74431293e-03]]
        [[  7.45317191e-02   9.24890220e-01   5.78058825e-04]]
        [[  4.23816502e-01   1.95193406e-05   5.76164007e-01]]
        [[  5.45647919e-01   1.01446029e-04   |\bfseries{4.54250574e-01}|]]
        ....
    \end{minted}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

But if I change to text seems that can not accept \bfseries but works with bf:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\begin{document}


    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,autogobble,xleftmargin=0.1\textwidth,xrightmargin=0.1\textwidth,frame=single]{text}
        [[  1.21105916e-03   9.98751879e-01   3.69788831e-05]]
        [[  9.31845248e-01   8.14934465e-05   6.80731535e-02]]
        [[  2.51991690e-08   1.38797950e-05   9.99986053e-01]]
        [[  2.20720409e-04   3.13331257e-05   9.99747932e-01]]
        [[  2.88604596e-03   9.97110307e-01   3.71164833e-06]]
        [[  9.65342045e-01   1.14912807e-04   3.45430225e-02]]
        [[  9.35987046e-05   2.29562909e-04   9.99676824e-01]]
        [[  3.64742687e-06   1.02245028e-03   9.98973966e-01]]
        [[  9.98075962e-01   1.79647308e-04   1.74431293e-03]]
        [[  7.45317191e-02   9.24890220e-01   5.78058825e-04]]
        [[  4.23816502e-01   1.95193406e-05   5.76164007e-01]]
        [[  5.45647919e-01   1.01446029e-04   |\bf{4.54250574e-01}|]]
        ....
    \end{minted}


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You change the format from bash to text, but its ok...

Comment: @dfh, the funny thing is that I am working on debian... (Anyway... please if you agree, change your title to "bold letters within minted (bash/text)" ... this way it will be more helpful I think.)